# Сумма чисел из атрибутов отмеченных checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть много чекбоксов на странице

```
<form id="form">
<input class="check" data-price="10" name="check_list[]" value="11" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" data-price="11" name="check_list[]" value="22" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" data-price="12" name="check_list[]" value="33" type="checkbox">
</form>
```

как сосчитать сумму из `data-price` отмеченных чекбоксов?

Comment: `let prices = 0; document.querySelectorAll('[data-price]:checked').forEach((el) => { prices += parseInt(el.dataset.price); }); console.log(prices);`

Answer (score 0):

- надо выбрать элементы по нужному селектору `$( "input.check:checked")` (jquery)
- пробежаться циклом по ним и сложить их значения аттрибута `data-price` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) в итоговую переменную.

---

Для облегчения подсчета суммы можно воспользоваться методом [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) на массиве

Массив можно сделать например так:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input.check:checked"));
```